# How can I avoid running 'npm run build' after every change

Tags: javascript, html, npm, webpack

I haven't found a suitable answer for my issue. I'm using NPM and Webpack, and every time I modify my JS files, I have to run the command, which is very frustrating.

Is there a way to avoid this delay of 5 seconds for every small change?

Comment: It's not clear _how_ you're using NPM and Webpack. Webpack has a [dev server](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/) though, maybe you should read up on that?

Comment: Yes, live reload is built into many libraries these days. Tell us more about your situation.

Comment: @jonrsharpe hm im using Blockly library that I downloaded via NPM install. Then in the Webpack config file I just bundle my index.js that includes "import blockly...." so every time i do changes to my index.js i must run the command npm run build to bundle my index.js... (im using vscode liveserver extention)

Answer (score 0):

You can install watch. `npm install watch`
When watch is installed, add "watch": `watch npm run build ./directory-you-want-to-track`
Run `npm run watch`
This is pretty much just auto-save. It checks all the files inside a directory and when you change something or on-save, it will re-run all the scripts inside package.json.

Comment: I installed watch and places this in my package.json `"watch": "watch npm run build ./resources"`, but when I run: `npm run watch` I'm getting this error:  no such file or directory, stat 'C:\laragon\www\..\run'